# Glibcxx 3.4.15 cannot be found

Tags: c++, gcc, centos6.5

I installed sirius IPA server on my centos 6.6 VPS. When I pass queries to the server, I get the below error and I see that its related to GCC version.

```
/root/sirius-1.0.1/sirius-application/question-answer/lib/search/libindri_jni.so:
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found
(required by /root/sirius-1.0.1/sirius-application/question-answer/lib/search/libindri_jni.so)
```

So I ran `strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBC` and the output was:

```
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBC_2.2.5
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

I tried to compile gcc 4.6 from source but the compiling went for almost 1.5 hours with 199% of cpu utilization and I had to shut it down to prevent resource hogging. I cannot compile the source using different GCC because its already compiled one. How can I solve this?